# BigQuery Error while running query on prod

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, pm2

So this is the error I am getting

```
ApiError: Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [2:18]
1|index  |     at new ApiError (/home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:75:15)
1|index  |     at /home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/bigquery.js:1074:23
1|index  |     at /home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:412:25
1|index  |     at Util.handleResp (/home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:161:9)
1|index  |     at /home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:534:22
1|index  |     at onResponse (/home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:240:7)
1|index  |     at /home/sahil_bswgames_com/LudoRConfData/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:226:13
1|index  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
1|index  |   code: undefined,
1|index  |   errors: [
1|index  |     {
1|index  |       reason: 'invalidQuery',
1|index  |       location: 'query',
1|index  |       message: 'Syntax error: Missing whitespace between literal and alias at [2:18]'
1|index  |     }
1|index  |   ],
```

and following is my query

```
SELECT assetId,  date, uniqueUsers as uniqueUsershavingP1 FROM table WHERE date between '2022-10-01' and  '2022-10-25" and event= "abc"
```

What is wrong in this query, because query is running perfectly on local but not on prod

I have tried to put table name in quotes as suggested by many articles bt that did'nt work either

Comment: Can you share the sql query generated by your JavaScript code ? I suspect it missing backtick char when you reference your table.

Comment: '2022-10-25"  <-- you're using single quote and double quote at the same time. would you try after fixing this first ?